# syncronize drupal 7 users with magento 1.7 customers

Tags: users

The Module that is available in drupal is supporting the previous versions of Drupal (D6) and Magento(1.6). You can find it here

```
http://drupal.org/project/magento
```

I am using D7 with Magento 1.7, Is anybody out here can suggest me a flow how to add records in customer table while users are registering in drupal, Since i am very new to drupal as well as magento i am finding it a bit difficult to hack into D7 functions

Can this method be followed?

```
http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/09/07/how-to-pull-the-list-of-customers-from-magento-to-an-external-site/
```

Does this method have any security vulnerabilities associated with it?

I only need to add a few fields like

```
First Name
Last Name
Email
Password
Entity_type_id
```

Rest of the customer details can be updated using the magento engine itself once the user is logged in

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to trigger an action whenever a new user is created (and/or updated which will also matter in your scenario). This action can be a PHP script so the possibilities you have to interact with other software (Magento) are endless.

Comment: Thanks for introducing Rules. I will now start exploring that and will update the result here

Comment: I have set up a rule like after user registers redirect to drupal url, and i am passing http://localhost/drupal2/custom/dtom?[account:uid]. the user_id is coming in the url correctly. but when i try to print the argument it is an array with no value in it. what am i doing wrong

Comment: Maybe you should consider creating a different question with the details of the new problem you are facing.

Comment: I fetch the value using arg(). Its working fine now.